# Delete message from Gmail "All Mail" folder via IMAP

Tags: php, imap, flags, gmail-imap

I am accessing Gmail All Mail folder via IMAP, using [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). I need to delete a message (Move to Trash or Permanently delete) from the folder. The following commands do not seem to work:

```
UID STORE 123 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
EXPUNGE
```

I can modify labels using [X-GM-LABELS](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels), but there is no option to add a "Trash" label.

The RFC 3501, does not have a "MOVE" command, so I need to copy the message to "Trash" folder and then remove it from the parent folder. What's the way out??

**Found partial answer.**

To set Trash as a label, we need to use "\\Trash" as the label. Here are the commands to move the message to trash (delete inbox label and add trash label).

```
UID STORE 123 -X-GM-LABELS (\\Inbox)
UID STORE 123 +X-GM-LABELS (\\Trash)
```

Now, I am stuck on how to delete the message permanently.

Answer (score 0):

These commands delete the message permanently:

```
// sequence number 123, 234 are the same message in different folders
SELECT "[Gmail]/AllMail"
COPY 123 "[Gmail]/Trash"
CLOSE

SELECT "[Gmail]/Trash"
STORE 234 +FLAGS (\Deleted)
EXPUNGE
```

Just tried it out and it works.