# how to change messages of draftbox for mailcore2

Tags: mailcore2

I would like to modify the contents of Drafts, and synchronized to the mailcore server. There mailcore2 API provides it? if not, is there some better way? please tell me.

Comment: You need to remove the old message and append a new one.

Comment: thanks you~ but, remove the old messgae will into DeletedMailbox,how can I Completely remove it. let it not exist in the mailbox.

Comment: I think this post will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783109/delete-message-from-gmail-all-mail-folder-via-imap

Comment: I do not really understand，I use mailcore2 imap in ios。